# Catch strings not wrapped in span

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an html root element looks like this:

```
<div>
    <span>first</span>
    second
    <span>third</span>
    fourth
<div>
```

Now i need to wrap `third` and `fourth` with span like others, So the result will be:

```
<div>
    <span>first</span>
    <span>second</span>
    <span>third</span>  
    <span>fourth</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you want this done with regex according to the tag? Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14055983 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this the browser I would recommend you do not use regular expressions but instead use the DOM handling capabilites built into the browser. (There are good reasons for not using RegExp for parsing HTML, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) to get a first impression)

When you walk through the DOM tree you can use [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) to distinguish between nodes that are Tags (called "element nodes") and nodes that only contain text.

```
  div = document.querySelector('div');
  for( let child of div.childNodes ) {
    if (child.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && /\w/.test(child.data) ) {
      console.log("type", child.nodeType, "for", child.data);
      let newChild = document.createElement('span');
      newChild.textContent = child.data;
      div.replaceChild(newChild, child)
    }
  }
```

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/bjelline/pen/rNeVGJj)

Comment: That's why I've posted this question. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```js
let html = `<div>
    <span>first</span>
    second
    <span>third</span>
    fourth
<div>`

const formatHTML = (html) => {
  return html
    .split(/\r?\n/)
    .map((item) => {
      item = item.trim();
      if (item === '<div>' || item.indexOf('<span>') > -1) {
        return item;
      } else {
        return `<span>${item}</span>`;
      }
    })
    .join('\n');
}

console.log(formatHTML(html));
```